# Error "Cannot write to" using wget

Tags: wget

I want to make a backup script that downloads the content of a SharePoint folder. I got a working command using wget (when previously login and export the cookie.txt) using the following command:

```
wget --cookies=on --load-cookies cookies-portal-holding-lknoe-at.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate -N -r -l 10 -np -R "index.html*" https://sharepoint.url/path/Freigegebene%20Dokumente/Foldername
```

The options are:

```
-N to turn on timestamping
-R to exclude index.html 
-r -l 10 to download 10 recursive levels
-np to start with the child of the specified path
```

The command works as expected, when the destination folder does not exist. When it does exist, the following error is displayed:

```
sharepoint.url/path/Freigegebene%20Dokumente/Foldername: Is a directory
Cannot write to sharepoint.url/path/Freigegebene%20Dokumente/Foldername (Success).
```

I did not run out of disk space... Any ideas?

Comment: I think you’re expecting wget to work like rsync and only copy down the diffs as needed to get up to date, but that’s not how it works.  On the other hand, rsync may be able to connect using https and if so it is likely a better tool for the job.  I recommend you check both man pages as the next step.

Comment: rsync is not able to connect using https.

Comment: Maybe you need `--trust-server-names` wget option.

Comment: What output do you get if you run `ls -l sharepoint.url/path/Freigegebene%20Dokumente`?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the "/" at the end of the directory. Try:

`wget --cookies=on --load-cookies cookies-portal-holding-lknoe-at.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate -N -r -l 10 -np -R "index.html*" https://sharepoint.url/path/Freigegebene%20Dokumente/Foldername/`